# Workflow Rule Firing Question

Tags: workflow

I have a WFR that needs to fire an email alert when the record type of a contact is not equal to "conflict of interest".

I currently have the rule criteria set as: DV_Perpetrator_Opposing_Party__r.RecordTypeId <> "012J00000009aeV"

The rule is active and the email alert action is set up properly. What am I missing that this is not firing properly? I have added my personal email to the additional recipients to ensure email sending is working. I have also checked my spam. Any other suggestions? I'm hoping my rule criteria is just off.

Comment: Much better to use `RecordType.DeveloperName != "<some_value>"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enable deliverability to All Email

[image]